# Not able to draw Bar graph using chart.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, draw

What I want to do is to draw a bar graph using a canvass but it's not working. I am using the chart.js library (from chartjs.org) to draw bar graph.

I have put my  tag inside Detail2->Stats but no bar is drawn. The same thing works when I put the canvas outside the "main". Following is the code.

Comment: Is anything shown in the console when you draw it?

Comment: No nothing comes up in the console. I cant see the canvas part. It draws when I put the canvas outside of the main.